# Use a message for a topic in Confluent.Kafka when consumer run

Tags: .net-core, apache-kafka, message-queue, apache-zookeeper

I'm using Confluent.Kafka(1.4.4) in a .netCore project as a message broker. In the startup of the project I set only "bootstrapservers" to the specific servers which were in the appSetting.json file and I produce messages in an API when necessary with the code below in related class:

```
public async Task WriteMessage<T>(string topicName, T message)
    {
        using (var p = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(_producerConfig).Build())
        {
            try
            {
                var serializedMessage= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
                var dr = await p.ProduceAsync(topicName, new Message<Null, string> { Value = serializedMessage });
                logger.LogInformation($"Delivered '{dr.Value}' to '{dr.TopicPartitionOffset}'");
            }
            catch (ProduceException<Null, string> e)
            {
                logger.LogInformation($"Delivery failed: {e.Error.Reason}");
            }
        }
    }
```

I have also added the following code In the consumer solution :

```
public async Task Run()
    {
        using (var consumerBuilder = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(_consumerConfig).Build())
        {
            consumerBuilder.Subscribe(new List<string>() { "ActiveMemberCardForPanClubEvent", "CreatePanClubEvent", "RemovePanClubEvent"
            });

            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Console.CancelKeyPress += (_, e) =>
            {
                e.Cancel = true; // prevent the process from terminating.
                cts.Cancel();
            };

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var consumer = consumerBuilder.Consume(cts.Token);
                        if (consumer.Message != null)
                        {
                            using (LogContext.PushProperty("RequestId", Guid.NewGuid()))
                            {
                                //Do something
                                logger.LogInformation($"Consumed message '{consumer.Message.Value}' at: '{consumer.TopicPartitionOffset}'.");
                                await DoJob(consumer.Topic, consumer.Message.Value);
                                consumer.Topic.Remove(0, consumer.Topic.Length);
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            logger.LogInformation($"message is null for topic '{consumer.Topic}'and partition : '{consumer.TopicPartitionOffset}' .");
                            consumer.Topic.Remove(0, consumer.Topic.Length);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (ConsumeException e)
                    {

                        logger.LogInformation($"Error occurred: {e.Error.Reason}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // Ensure the consumer leaves the group cleanly and final offsets are committed.
                consumerBuilder.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I produce a message and when the consumer project is run everything goes perfectly and the message is being read in the consumer solution.
The problem is raised when the consumer project is not run and I queue a message in the API with the message producer in API. After running consumers there is not any valid message for that topic that it's message is being produced.
I am familiar with and have experiences with message brokers and I know that by sending a message it will be on the bus until it is being used but I don't understand why it doesn't work with Kafka in this project.

Comment: Kafka topics have cleanup policies in place based on time or byte size. The default retention time is 7 days. It is *not* deleting messages until it has been consumed once. Check your topic configuration related to "retention".

Comment: so why the produced message for the topic is null after running consumer?

Comment: Sorry, I might have misinterpreted your sentence "After running consumers there is not any valid message for that topic that it's message is being produced." Can you try to rephrase it or show some example messages?

Comment: the problem is solved the ticked answer is the solution to my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default setting for the "auto.offset.reset" Consumer property is "latest".

That means (in the context of no offsets being written yet) if you write a message to some topic and then subsequently start the consumer, it will skip past any messages written before the consumer was started. This could be why your consumer is not seeing the messages queued by your producer.

The solution is to set "auto.offset.reset" to "earliest" which means that the consumer will start from the earliest offset on the topic.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#auto.offset.reset

Comment: exactly it works fine for me and the problem is solved. Thanks for your answer and I would be so grateful if you please give a positive point to my question

Comment: again thanks for your answer but I still have another problem after solving the previous problem I noticed that whenever I restart the consumer project the message being consumed in the previous session still is valid and it is repeatedly being used. do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: Once you have successfully processed a message, you can "commit" it's offset. Your consumer API probably has some kind of commit method you can use to do this. Here's the java method https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitSync--